# Get the list of maintainers in GitHub GraphQL API?

Tags: github, github-api

I would like to use the GitHub GraphQL API to fetch a list of accounts that have control of a given public repo.

This would include anyone who can:

- Make commits
- Approve pull requests
- Create releases
- Administrate the repo
- etc.

Is this possible using the GraphQL API? And if so, what would the query be?

Comment: Are you a member of the organization which owns these repositories or otherwise have access to them other than as a member of the public?

Comment: @bk2204 No I want to do this analysis on any public repo

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible in the general case.  There's the concept of secret teams where the users aren't publicly visible, and those teams can have access to repositories.  The REST API endpoints don't allow you to query the team list of an arbitrary public repository, so the GraphQL endpoints won't allow that, either.